# how to check if a space is followed by a certain character?

Tags: java

I am really confused on this regex things. I have tried to understand it, went no where.

Basically, i am trying to replace all spaces followed by every character but a space to be replaced with "PM".

" sd"
"  sd"

however

"  sd"
"  sd"

Comment: `This should be a piece of cake for you all.`: wouldn't it be better if you were to *try* first and show us your attempt rather than simply dump this here without showing the fruits of your efforts? Then  you would change a "begging for the code" type question to a "please help me learn what I'm doing wrong" type question, and both you and we get much more satisfaction from the latter.

Comment: my apologies...i had it up to this part "( [^ ]?)"

Comment: No problem, and no down-vote. But for future reference, it's so much more satisfying for us to work on the latter types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the space and the following character with "PM":

```
String s = "123 axy cq23 dasd"; //your string
String newString = s.replaceAll(" [^ ]","PM");
```

Since I'm not sure if you want to replace only the space or the space and the following character, too, here is a slightly modified version that replaces only the space:

```
String s = "123 axy cq23 dasd"; //your string
String newString = s.replaceAll(" ([^ ])", "PM$1")
```

Comment: Just remember to assign the result to some string, as strings are immutable.

Comment: You're right, this is in fact confusing. You could also leave it out and get the same result as {1,1} means: Minimum 1 character, Maximum 1 character. I edited the answer by removing the {1,1}.

Comment: out of curiosity, where would i ever use those brackets. can u update the answer providing an example of that? thank u

Answer (score 1):

You need to use non-capturing pattern:

```
String res = oldString.replaceAll(" (?:[^ ])", "PM");
```